# MySQL Workbench Import CSV File Restrition

Tags: mysql, csv, import, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to import a csv file into MySQL 5.7 using the MySQL Workbench import module.
It's everything ok, the data are correctly readed by the module.

But I have 11.000 rows.
The module are just importing 29.

Is there any configuration restricting my full import?

Comment: What app are you using? Any error messages or something?

Comment: Sorry, I'm using the MySQL Workbench. There is no error reported.

Comment: Try http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html

Comment: Which method of import provided by MySQL Workbench do you use? Power import or Data import?

Comment: What version of Workbench? 6.3.5? There have been related bug fixes.

Comment: Workbench 6.3.5 build 201. 64 bits version.

Comment: Importing 29 out of 11,000 rows sounds like a bug. Please submit a bug report. You might want to save your first 40 or so rows somewhere for testing as perhaps a certain type of data is causing an issue.

Comment: Ok Philip, I will do this. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problems as yours. I got around it by the following steps:

1. after the MySQL Workbench import clear all the table rows by truncate(but reserve the table itself)
2. Using MySQL command line
   LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/data.csv' INTO TABLE my_table FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','

Hope it helps.